# Unable to call private repo in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a private repo which has all GitHub Actions in it. I'm calling the custom actions from that repo into my another private repo in same org. While doing so I'm getting below error.

```
Error: Unable to resolve action <org_name/repo_name>, repository not found
```

This error is only with one of the private repo and custom actions are being called and executed successfully into my another private repos in same org.

All permissions are in also in place. Public actions are being executed successfully in this repo. The issue is only with custom actions from private repo.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because the user on your dev machine is usually associated with a particular GitHub account and that account has access to the private repository, whereas the GitHub Actions user can only see the repository it's attached to

Comment: That's not correct; sharing actions from a private repository is definitely possible, see [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-from-your-private-repository).

Comment: Yes it it possible. I can access my actions from one private repo to another private repo. But facing issue for some particular repos only. Not getting what is blocking this.